# prevent creating related objects while adding objects to many to many fields in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

I have already referred to [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706072/drf-3-creating-many-to-many-update-create-serializer-with-though-table) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124555/django-rest-framework-disable-field-update-after-object-is-created)  like these and a [bug](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1556) on github repo of DRF. I am still unclear if this is bug still exists as the info i fetched so far is not from recent posts. I am trying to create an api using django rest framework. below given is my code.

#### Serializers.py

```
class MemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'email')

class TeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    members = MemberSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ('name', 'members')
class TeamUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'members', 'team_type', 'created_by')
```

#### Views.py

```
class TeamViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Team.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TeamSerializer
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Team.objects.filter(created_by=self.request.user)
        return queryset
```

members is a `M2M` relationship to django user model. I can create a new object, get the details but upon updating an existing Team model bby adding a new user to member field, it says `a user with that username exists`.  I can override `save()` method or `switch to another serializer` in the `update()` method of my `modelserializer` to solve the issue.

```
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
    instance = self.get_object()
    members = request.data['members']
    member_list = list()
    for member in members:
        member_list.append(User.objects.get(username=member['username']).id)
    request.data['members'] = member_list
    serializer = TeamSerializerUpdate(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_update(serializer)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

But I am not sure if that is the right thing to do. It would be very helpful if a workaround for this is devised.

TIA

Comment: There is an indent error after the line `class TeamUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):`. I imagine that the following 2 lines should be indented and no more. There is a suggested edit for something else but it'd be better to review and correct it yourself.

Comment: The indents on get_queryset were/are wrong as well but my edit needs peer reviewed...

Comment: My bad. thanks for pointing it out. But Indentation is not really the issue here. Why does drf keeps creating related objects of M2M fields on a put request?

Comment: Nobody suggested the indents were the issue but resolving them will save the next person who comes along a few seconds so worth doing. Regarding your issue, I've never used M2M with DRF so can't help - sorry. When I am doing something similar I use nested sets so would simply add my one new user to /teams/1/members/, for example.